# Vue - going from one component to another on button click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm very new to Vue. I'm wondering if there's a way to go from one component to another. So for example, I have component 1 which has a header component in it that has a button that should make component 1 change to component 2 which has the same header with a button that should take me to component 3 and so on.

I've looked into routing, I'm still new so I'm not sure if that's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it using vue-router, install it via npm.

Put your header with buttons before the tag

`<router-view></router-view>`